# Django. How to get value from multiple checkboxes

Tags: django, post, checkbox

Hey I have seen many questions about this but i dont know why it isnt working for me. I have this piece of code in my `home.html` file:

```
<form action="/result/" method="post">
<div class="form-locat-att">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Location: <input type="text" name="location_input" required/>
    <p></p><br>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-round", name="search_button">Search</button>
    <p></p>

    <h5>Zabytki</h5> <p></p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="museum" name="att[]" value=" Museum OR">
    <label for="muzeum"> Museum</label> &nbsp;

    <input type="checkbox" id="statue" name="att[]" value=" Statue OR">
    <label for="pomnik"> Statue</label> &nbsp;

    <input type="checkbox" id="castle" name="att[]" value=" Castle OR">
    <label for="zamek"> Castle</label> &nbsp;

    <input type="checkbox" id="palace" name="att[]" value=" Palace OR">
    <label for="palac"> Palace</label> <p></p>

</div>
</form>
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'search_button' in request.POST:

        attrac = request.POST.getlist('att[]')
        locat = request.POST.get('location_input')

        print(attrac)

        # (here i have some irrelevant code where i render my context)
        return render(request, 'przewodnik_app/result.html', context)
    return render(request, 'przewodnik_app/result.html')
```

I am trying to print `attrac` which should give me values from the checkboxes i've checked. When i use the .get method with id for example
request.POST.get('museum')
it returns correct value. When i am using `name` the list is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine for me, printing out:

```
# print(request.POST) prints out
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ty1QJh1jQpwt1Bgd77lLJqyudgSLt5wGCx4zSfh9Iwak02A4J8JiliMHPZa034v6'], 'location_input': ['Holland'], 'search_button': [''], 'att[]': [' Museum OR', ' Castle OR', ' Palace OR']}>
        
# request.POST.getlist('att[]') prints out
[' Museum OR', ' Castle OR', ' Palace OR']
```

You also do not need to do `if request.method == 'POST' and 'search_button' in request.POST:`

A button without a type is by default a submit button submitting everything with a `name` attribute within the `<form>` tags (but you should give it a type), so instead of

`<button class="btn btn-block btn-round", name="search_button">Search</button>`

you should do

`<button class="btn btn-block btn-round", type='submit'>Search</button>`

and then just `if request.method == 'POST':`